# Accessing camera from within the photo library with UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiimagepickercontroller

There are tons of examples on how to add a button to access the photo library from the camera view, but I can’t seem to find anything about doing it the other way around.

In my app the primary source of the images would be the library, but I also want to let the users use the camera if they really want to. If possible I would like to avoid the additional step of presenting an action sheet with the two options (library and camera) or some similar solution. Also, I would prefer not to have two dedicated buttons.

Answer (score 0):

I use this code:

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
  self.imgPicker  = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

  if(buttonIndex == 0) {
    if([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {
      self.imgPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
      self.imgPicker.allowsEditing = NO;
      self.imgPicker.delegate = self;
      self.imgPicker.videoQuality = UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeHigh;
    }
  }

  if(buttonIndex == 1) {
    if([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary])  {
      self.imgPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
      self.imgPicker.allowsEditing = NO;
      self.imgPicker.delegate = self;
    }
  }
  [self performSelector:@selector(showPicker) withObject:self afterDelay:0.6f];
}

- (void)showPicker {
  [self presentModalViewController:self.imgPicker animated:YES];
}
```